# Swift:adding UIScroll view Programmatically does not scroll in view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement the `UIScrollView` programatically.

The main reason behind this is I have first added the views in my `ViewController` and finally i found that i forget to add the scroll view in my `ViewController`. Now i want to add it programiticaly but does not gets added in the view. I have searched everywhere and tried but did not helped yet.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var UIViewHeader: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnRegisteredCourses: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var scrollView: UIScrollView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = view.bounds.size
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(UIViewHeader)
    scrollView.addSubview(lblName)
    scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
    scrollView.addSubview(btnRegisteredCourses)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
  }
```

Comment: UIScrollView can scroll if the `contentSize` is greater than its frame size. So you just need to set `contentSize` with height greater than scroll's frame height (in case vertical scrolling).

Comment: oh thank you..i was unaware about this.. :) :)

Comment: ok i set the content size greater to the height. but only scroll bar scrolls with out scrolling the view?

Comment: Because of the subViews you added was created before and they are related with `self.view`, they are the subViews of `self.view`. Try the answer of @Sandeep Kumar. If it cannot fix, try to create all of subViews programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)

}
```

Comment: i can just find the scroll bar and bar only scrolls but does not scroll the view

Answer (score 1):

Increase scroll view content size and try it again.

and you have to remove UIViewHeader, lblName, tableView, btnRegisteredCourses from super view and after that add to scroll view.

Comment: do you mean contentSize?

Answer (score 1):

Try This content will also scroll:

```
 @IBOutle var UIViewHeader: UIView!
@IBOutle var btnRegisteredCourses: UIButton!
@IBOutle var lblName: UILabel!
@IBOutle var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true

UIViewHeader.removeFromSuperview()
lblName.removeFromSuperview()
tableView.removeFromSuperview()
btnRegisteredCourses.removeFromSuperview()
    scrollView.addSubview(UIViewHeader)
    scrollView.addSubview(lblName)
    scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
    scrollView.addSubview(btnRegisteredCourses)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
  }
```

Comment: can you explain why we are removing from superView?

Comment: it is working?. Because in storyboard these views are added to self.view not on scrollview.

Comment: i am trying to implement,it's taking time

Comment: it is still problem. only scroll bar moves without views

Comment: Add all content to view in storyboard and then add view to scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which type of scrolling you want, you have to set the `contentSize` of `scrollView`. For example

For Horizontal Scrolling:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIViewHeader.frame.size.width + lblName.frame.size.width + tableView.frame.size.width + btnRegisteredCourses.frame.size.width , height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

For Vertical Scrolling:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.frame.size.width , height: UIViewHeader.frame.size.height + lblName.frame.size.height + tableView.frame.size.height + btnRegisteredCourses.frame.size.height)
```

Do like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.frame.size.width , height: UIViewHeader.frame.size.height + lblName.frame.size.height + tableView.frame.size.height + btnRegisteredCourses.frame.size.height)
    }
```

Comment: Views are not being scrolled

Comment: @Samjhana, set scrollView content size in viewWillAppear

Comment: sorry i did no get what you means

Answer (score 0):

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var UIViewHeader: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnRegisteredCourses: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)       //1000 change to the scollview's size.
    scrollView.addSubview(UIViewHeader)
    scrollView.addSubview(lblName)
    scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
    scrollView.addSubview(btnRegisteredCourses)
   view.addSubview(scrollView)

}
 }
```

** Note:- But Above code reset all constraints **

Comment: Views are not being scrolled

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Steve Hancock's answer in the similar question: [UIScrollView not scrolling at all when added programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291053/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-at-all-when-added-programmatically-in-swift)

There is a lot of answers suggesting content size but this sometimes is not the solution. The problem lies in how the scroll view interacts with your views inside, and it is a good tendency to embed all your subviews inside a global UIView  which is in turn embedded in the UIScrollView. This is a rough example on how you would set it up:

let scrollView = ScrollView()
let contentView = UIView()
(initialized above for simplicity)

```
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true      
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

(you always want to make your scrollview longer than your view)

```
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    coachView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
```

All of your subviews will go inside your contentView with their respective constraints.Technically you do not need the centerX anchors if you have a leading and a trailing but setting constraints for a scroll view can be a trial and error endeavor, especially if you have a subview with dynamic height. I have seen contentViews shift to the right for no apparent reason without the centerX anchor, and I have seen contentView lean to the left with a centerX anchor but without leading and trailing anchors